# How to update the global dictionary with another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My requirement is to update a dictionary with another one, once all the condition satisfies.
Here is a similar code snippet;

```
hello = {}
he = {"a":1}
j = 0
def abc(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        hello["b"] = i   #<----- Error occurs here
        print hello      #<----- Error occurs here
    else:
        hello.clear()    #<----- Error occurs here
        hello = he       #Because of this line error occurs in the above lines
        print hello
while j < 15:
    print "j = ", j
    abc(j)
    j += 1
```

When I declare the global in `def abc(i)`, the error goes away but the output is just bizzare.

```
hello = {}
he = {"a":1}
j = 0
def abc(i):
    global he, hello
    if i % 2 == 0:
        hello["b"] = i
        print hello
    else:
        hello.clear()
        hello = he
        print hello
while j < 15:
    print "j = ", j
    abc(j)
    j += 1
```

It clears and updates both `hello` and `he` automatically, where as there are no operatiosn are happening on `he`.
How to resolve this problem.

Comment: There's a lot going on here; first of all, you want to be careful when using global variables. In this case it is probably better to pass `hello` and `he` as parameters to `abc`. Secondly, when you set `hello = he`, you are not copying the contents of `he` to `hello`, you are creating a binding. Read here for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: when you set `hello` to `he` you basically point `hello` to `he` instead of creating a new copy

Comment: We should also note that the `hello` inside the function is local to that function because of the default behavior of the assignment operator. The `hello = he` line does not affect the `hello` variable at the top of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `hello` to be global when you assign `he` to it, but just saying `hello = he` makes `hello` *reference* `he`.  It is now just another name for the same dictionary.  To fix your problem, say `hello = he.copy()`